# How to Start program when Pi boots up

Tags: screen, terminal, python-3

I am making a system, in which I need to be able to make the pi autologin and run a python3 script without a monitor or password. The script requires human input from a keyboard, but it doesn't work with systemd, and the console autologin doesn't go until a monitor is plugged in.

Yes, the keyboard input will be 'blind', but that's alright. I have access to SSH and a monitor for setup, but no screen or SSH when it runs.

I am using Raspbian stretch lite, and a pi 3 b

Comment: are you enabling autologin in `raspi-config`?

Comment: No idea with systemd, with sysvinit you'd add your script to /etc/rc.local.

Comment: If the human input is deterministic, surely you can generate it by script so you don't need the human?

Comment: @John You should [merge your accounts](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) if you are indeed the author of this post; that way, you will be able to edit your post without others having to review your suggestions.